# Why doesn't this program print one character at a time?

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I was going through K&R's the C Programming Language, and came across this bit of code:

```
main()
{
  int c;

  while ((c=getchar()) != EOF)
    putchar(c);
}
```

I understand the reason the above code doesn't print one character at a time, immediately after `getchar()` gets the character input from the `stdin`, is because `stdin` only sends the input to the program's input buffer *after* the user hits `Enter`.

However, the function `getchar()` still reads one character at a time from the input buffer, and passes said character to `putchar()` to print. Why doesn't `putchar()` print the character immediately after getting it? Does it also wait for a `newline` character before printing, and store everything in its own buffer?

Comment: Tl;Dr Your stdout stream is line buffered, so it will not print immideatly. Set it to unbuffered or flush it with fflush(stdout) to do so

Comment: Take a look [HERE](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html)

Comment: How do you know putchar doesn't print the character immediately after getting it?

Comment: @immibis Then the output for "abc" would look like "aabbcc", i.e., each character would have been printed immediately after getting it.

Comment: @SomenathSinha But I thought you already established that `getchar` doesn't return any characters until you press enter. If `getchar` is still waiting for you to press enter then obviously your program hasn't called `putchar` yet.

Comment: @immibis That makes total sense. Thank you for the explanation.